# How can I know the promise function calling is caught exception or not

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have two simple function as below, one is callback and another one is Promise, in call back function, I can know whether the function caller caught the exception, but in the promise function I don't know how to handle it.

First one

```
  let call = function(a,b,success,fail){
      if(a==b){
         success();
       }
      else{
         if(fail){
           fail();
         }
         else{
           alert("a is not equal b");
         }
       }
  }
```

The second one

```
   let call = function(a,b){
     return new Promise(resolve,reject){
        if(a==b){
          resolve();
        }
        else{
           //I want to code here, if the call is not catch error, 
           //the system alert("a is not equal b"), otherwise call the reject.           
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: There is no good way to know whether the caller is handling a promise rejection.  There are hacks that work in some circumstances, but I would not suggest going there.  ALL promises require that the caller handle any possible rejections - it is not optional.  That is the law with promises.  That's part of the contract for using your API.  That's not your API's responsibility itself to try to make up for a client writing bad code.

Comment: FYI, in the first one, you also can't stop the user from passing `function() {}` for the `fail` handler either.  Moral of the story - it's your client's responsibility to handle errors properly.

Comment: @jfriend00, thank you very much for your answer, I want to do something if the caller is not "catch exception"(or didn't pass the fail function), such as alert the error info or others, otherwise the caller must be catch the exception and write the alert code every time,  if there isn't any method to handle when use promise that I can only ask the caller catch the exception and write the alert code when call it.

Comment: I think I've already explained that you can't reliably know whether the caller is or isn't catching promise rejections so that is not an option in your code.  Please reread my previous comment.

Comment: @jfriend00 Got it, so many thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to know whether the caller is handling a promise rejection. There are hacks that work in some circumstances, but I would not suggest going there.

ALL promises require that the caller handle any possible rejections - it is not optional. That is the law with promises. That's part of the contract for using your API. That's not your API's responsibility itself to try to make up for a client writing bad code and promises are not designed to make that feasible.

So, it's not an option for you to change your function's behavior based on whether a promise rejection is or isn't being handled.